# Indy Get response text while not handling 302

Tags: delphi, http, indy

```
    FHTTP.HandleRedirects := False;
    try

      StrPage := FHTTP.Get('https://somesite.site');
    except
    end;
```

There is redirect 302 , but i need to get text from this reqest..
Response:

```
    (Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
    Content-Length:148291
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Sun, 21 Sep 2014 09:13:49 GMT
    Expires:-1
    Location:/di
    Pragma:no-cache
```

In response :

```html
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/di">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
```

How cant i get this text?

Answer (score 4):

When `HandleRedirects := False`, 302 status code will cause `TIdHTTP` to raise an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception.
The content of the response can be accessed via the `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage`.

***Example:***

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StrPage: string;
begin
  IdHttp1.HandleRedirects := False;
  try
    StrPage := IdHttp1.Get('http://www.gmail.com/');
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      if not ((E.ErrorCode = 301) or (E.ErrorCode = 302)) then raise;
      StrPage := E.ErrorMessage;
      ShowMessage(StrPage);
    end
    else
      raise;
  end;
end;
```

***Output:***

```html
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://mail.google.com/mail/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @kobik's answer (which is technically accurate), there are some additional considerations.

The response body text you showed is fairly minimal, the only real piece of useful information it provides is a human-readable text message that includes an HTML link to the URL being redirected to.  If you are just interested in the URL, you can obtain it by itself from the `TIdHTTP.Response.Location` property, or from the `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event.  In the case of `OnRedirect`, you can set its `Handled` parameter to False to skip the actual redirection without having to set `HandleRedirets` to False.

If you do not want an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception being raised on 302, you can either enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, or else call `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` directly and specify 302 in its `AIgnoreReplies` property. Either way, you can then check the `TIdHTTP.Response.ResponseCode` property after the request exits without raising an exception. However, if you disable `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, you lose access to the body text (`TIdHTTP` will read and discard it) unless you enable the `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flag. Either way, you will have access to the response headers.

Comment: I didn't find anything like hoNoProtocolErrorException in HTTPOptions or anywhere else in idhttp.pas?  (v1.65 ships with XE2).

Comment: XE2 shipped with `IdHTTP.pas` revision 4682 (Indy 10.5.8). `hoNoProtocolErrorException` was added in revision 4936 (Indy 10.6.0, available in XE4), and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` was added in revision 5321 (Indy 10.6.2, available in 10.1 Berlin).  If you want to use them in XE2, you will have to upgrade your Indy installation.